# Symfony2: the best datagrid bundle

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid, bundle

Minimal functional needed:

1. Filterable
2. Sortable
3. Pagination
4. Export
5. Working with ORM, arrays, etc.
6. Twig
7. Mass actions
8. i18n

I liked it as is done in SonataAdminBundle, but I need it for frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use always [Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle)

Comment: Yep, i see it, looks good, but may be it is not the best :)

Comment: On github there is a large partecipation (with many forks) and on KNPBundles is the most voted under "Grid" research key (and without any dependencies with other bundles). For that reasons (and many others that you can surely see yourself) it is certainly the best bundle handles Grid actually ;-).